# Update marketing campaign paths based on time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark to process the following dataframe, so it can fit a marketing attribution model:

| user_id | timestamp | activity | campaign | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-01 10:00 | click | Holidays Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2021-12-31 09:00 | click | Holidays Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-13 15:59 | click | X Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-10 16:32 | click | Super Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-05 22:12 | click | Holidays Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-30 20:55 | event | NULL | purchase |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-30 22:10 | event | NULL | purchase |
| akalsds124 | 2022-01-31 10:13 | event | NULL | purchase |
| akalsds124 | 2022-02-03 04:55 | click | T8 Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-02-07 17:30 | click | Y Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-02-12 22:37 | event | NULL | purchase |
| akalsds124 | 2022-03-31 18:19 | click | U9 Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-04-02 23:08 | click | II Campaign | NULL |
| akalsds124 | 2022-03-02 07:00 | click | T8 Campaign | NULL |
| ijnbmshs33 | 2022-06-03 17:01 | click | Mega Campaign | NULL |
| ijnbmshs33 | 2022-05-03 10:31 | click | New Campaign | NULL |
| ijnbmshs33 | 2022-05-20 17:01 | click | Mega Campaign | NULL |

An event is an interaction inside the app (e.g. a purchase, login, etc) and a click activity is an ad click made by the user.

I need to create a path with each user's campaign touchpoints inside a list. Each list must include only the touchpoints that the user interacted up to 30 days before the purchase (date of purchase has to be taken into account).

The paths that did not lead to a purchase must be updated after 30 days (the last day of the 30-day window must be counted). The order of the touchpoints is important and duplicates cannot be eliminated.

The output should be like this:

| user_ID | path | converted | total_conversions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| akalsds124 | [Holidays Campaign,Holidays Campaign,Super Campaign,X Campaign] | 1 | 2 |
| akalsds124 | [Holidays Campaign,Super Campaign,X Campaign] | 1 | 1 |
| akalsds124 | [T8 Campaign, Y Campaign] | 1 | 1 |
| akalsds124 | [T8 Campaign, U9 Campaign] | 0 | 0 |
| akalsds124 | [II Campaign] | 0 | 0 |
| ijnbmshs33 | [New Campaign,Mega Campaign] | 0 | 0 |
| ijnbmshs33 | [Mega Campaign] | 0 | 0 |

You can create the dataframe by using this code:

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(
        [('akalsds124','2022-01-01 10:00','click','Holidays Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2021-12-31 09:00','click','Holidays Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-01-13 15:59','click','X Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-01-10 16:32','click','Super Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-01-05 22:12','click','Holidays Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-01-30 20:55','event','NULL','purchase'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-01-30 22:10','event','NULL','purchase'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-01-31 10:13','event','NULL','purchase'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-02-03 04:55','click','T8 Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-02-07 17:30','click','Y Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-02-12 22:37','event','NULL','purchase'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-03-31 18:19','click','U9 Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-04-02 23:08','click','II Campaign','NULL'),
         ('akalsds124','2022-03-02 07:00','click','T8 Campaign','NULL'),
         ('ijnbmshs33','2022-06-03 17:01','click','Mega Campaign','NULL'),
         ('ijnbmshs33','2022-05-03 10:31','click','New Campaign','NULL'),
         ('ijnbmshs33','2022-05-20 17:01','click','Mega Campaign','NULL')],
         ['user_id','timestamp','activity','campaign','event_name']
    )
```

Comment: How would you get the output for user ijnbmshs33? There is no event for this user. If I start with the latest click, I would get the path [Mega Campaign (2022-06-03), Mega Campaign (2022-05-20)] and the path [Mega Campaign (2022-05-20), New Campaign (2022-05-03)]?

Comment: @werner When the user does not convert (there isn't a purchase event for this user), we create a path with all the campaigns that the user interacted in a 30 day window. The days are counted from the first interaction onwards (first ad click). In this case, the user's (ijnbmshs33) first click was on the 'New Campaign' ad on 3 May 2022 at 10:31.  His next click was on a 'Mega Campaign' ad (2022-05-20 17:01). However, his last interaction is outside the initial 30 day window, because June 3rd 2022 would be the thirty second day. So, that is why this user would have two different paths.

Comment: @werner For this reason, this user's (ijnbmshs33) paths would be like this: [New Campaign,Mega Campaign] and [Mega Campaign]. Please, if you have any further comments or questions, please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you very much!

Comment: @programmer987 how come the for the purchase of event on 2022-02-12 22:37 only have two campaigns before ?

Comment: @Deku07 Because this user only interacted with two campaigns up to 30 days before the purchase. This user (akalsds124) clicked on the X Campaign on 2022-01-13 15:59. However, this date would represent the thirty first day before the purchase, because I am counting the day of purchase as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is using collect_list function on a bounded window. the below code could be first part of your answer

```
window = W.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('unixTime').rangeBetween(-3600*24*30, 0)
path_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('timestamp', F.col('timestamp').cast('timestamp'))
    .withColumn('unixTime', F.unix_timestamp('timestamp'))
    .withColumn('pathList', F.collect_list('campaign').over(window))
    .filter(F.col('event_name') == 'purchase')
)

path_df.sort('timestamp').show(truncate=False)
```